# Laravel: composer update error

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I run composer update, I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Below you can find a detailed description of the problem/output

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v4.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1
    - torann/geoip dev-master requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.4].
    - torann/geoip dev-master requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.4].
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - Installation request for torann/geoip dev-master -> satisfiable by torann/geoip[dev-master].
```

It is not clear to me what I should do to fix this? Should I downgrade laravel? I'm currently at 4.2.16

Comment: The problem seems to be that `torann/geoip` (at dev-master) requires Laravel 5.0. You might can fix this by specifying the version of the package (an older one that worked on Laravel 4)

Comment: I updated my composer.json file from "torann/geoip": "dev-master" to "torann/geoip": "0.1.*@dev" and it works :-) Thanks so much for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `torann/geoip` (at dev-master) requires Laravel 5.0. You can fix this by specifying an older version in your `composer.json` file.

As documented on the [github page](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip/tree/0.1.1), require it with:

```
"torann/geoip": "0.1.*@dev"
```